# Retrieve records from same name table from multiple databases in single result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with same name in all databases(3 DB's).

I have:

**Table**: `Table_test`

**Databases**:
1. `Test_DB`
2. `T_DB`
3. `Emp_DB`

**Note**: The table `Table_test` is stored in all three databases.

Now I want to retrieve records from same name table from multiple databases **WHERE** `Database` name start with `T`.

Comment: You will probably need dynamic sql which will be constructed after looping over sys.databases. Else you can use simple union all - `select * from Test_DB.dbo.foo union all select * from T_DB.dbo.foo union all select * from Emp_DB.dbo.foo`

Comment: @MAK Is 'name' column for the table ?

Comment: If the database names are always known, you don't need dynamic SQL, just `SELECT <column1>, <column2> FROM Test_DB.<schema>.Table_test UNION ALL SELECT <column1>, <column2> FROM T_DB.<schema>.Table_test UNION ALL SELECT <column1>, <column2> FROM Emp_DB.<schema>.Table_test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @list_DB varchar(100), @sql varchar(1000)
select @list_DB = stuff((select ',' + name
               from (select distinct DB_NAME(database_id) as name
                    from [sys].[dm_db_index_operational_stats](NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
                    where OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) = 'Table_test'
                        and DB_NAME(database_id) like 'T%') as A
               for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') + ','
declare @start int, @word nvarchar(4000), @charindex int, @i int
set @i=1
set @start=1
set @charindex= charindex(',', @list_DB, @start)
set @sql = ''
select @list_DB
while (@charindex <> 0)begin
    set @word= substring(@list_DB, @start, @charindex - @start)
    set @start= @charindex +1
    set @charindex= charindex(',', @list_DB, @start)
    set @sql = @sql + 'SELECT * FROM ' + @word + '.dbo.Table_test UNION ALL'
    set @i=@i+1
end

if @sql <> ''
    set @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 10)
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: There are some small errors! But I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Because I test in my DB. :)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know about it.

Comment: :) Haha.. Okay! Not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

## My Try:

First I have created table with name `Dbs` which contains all details of Databases which will be given by system stored procedure `sp_databases`.

**Table**: `Dbs`

```
CREATE TABLE Dbs
(
Database_Name VARCHAR(250),
Database_Size INT,
Remark VARCHAR(100)
);
```

**Insertion**: Inserting data from execution of system stored procedure `sp_databases`.

```
INSERT INTO Dbs exec sys.sp_databases;
```

**Script**: The following script prepare the select statement.

```
DECLARE @InnerQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @DB VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT Database_Name FROM Dbs
WHERE Database_Name LIKE 'T%' AND Database_Name != 'tempDB'

OPEN Cur1 
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @DB
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN

    SET @InnerQuery += 'SELECT * FROM '+@DB+'..Table_Test UNION ALL '
    PRINT('1');
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @DB;
    
END
CLOSE Cur1;
DEALLOCATE Cur1;

IF @InnerQuery <> ''
BEGIN
    SET @InnerQuery = LEFT(@InnerQuery,LEN(@InnerQuery)-10)
END

PRINT(@InnerQuery);

EXECUTE(@InnerQuery);
```

Please let me know about my small effort.